# Boost fast pool allocator has problems with function pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, function-pointers, allocator

Is this a Boost bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef const std::string key;
    typedef double* (*value)(const int&);
    std::map<key, value, std::less<key>> map_with_standard_allocator; // works
    std::map<key, value, std::less<key>, boost::fast_pool_allocator<std::pair<const key, value> > > map_with_boost_allocator; // fails
}
```

the last line fails to compile under MS Visual Studio 2008 with Boost 1.40 and 1.48. It compiles fine under g++ 4.5.3 (Cygwin), though.

The error is:

```
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>C:\UniLib1\trunk\External\boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp(205) : error C2535: 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> *boost::fast_pool_allocator<T,UserAllocator,Mutex,NextSize>::address(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : member function already defined or declared
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>,
1>            T=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>            UserAllocator=boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
1>            Mutex=boost::details::pool::default_mutex,
1>            NextSize=32
1>        ]
1>        C:\UniLib1\trunk\External\boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp(202) : see declaration of 'boost::fast_pool_allocator<T,UserAllocator,Mutex,NextSize>::address'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>            UserAllocator=boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
1>            Mutex=boost::details::pool::default_mutex,
1>            NextSize=32
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xtree(137) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::fast_pool_allocator<T,UserAllocator,Mutex,NextSize>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,
1>            UserAllocator=boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
1>            Mutex=boost::details::pool::default_mutex,
1>            NextSize=32
1>        ]
1>        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\map(78) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<key,value ,std::less<key>,boost::fast_pool_allocator<std::pair<key,value >>,false>
1>        ]
1>        .\main.cpp(9) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=key,
1>            _Ty=value,
1>            _Pr=std::less<key>,
1>            _Alloc=boost::fast_pool_allocator<std::pair<key,value >>
1>        ]
```

Comment: boost 1.40? arent we at 1.49 already?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `std::pair<const key, value>`?

Comment: @sixlettervariables I've added the compiler error.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I know, but that's the version I have to use -- don't ask me why :(

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks, fixed it, but the error's still there.

Comment: Why do you think this error has to do with function pointers? Does the code work if you make `value` another type?

Comment: @interjay You're right, the error occurs when the key of the map is `const std::string`. It works OK when the key is just `std::string`. It's a piece of legacy code which I'm modifying to use Boost allocator -- it somehow worked OK with standard STL allocator.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I've tested the code with Boost 1.48, and it still fails to compile. It does compile under g++ 4.5.3, so it looks like a Visual Studio issue. I guess the next question is, who's right, Boost or Microsoft? Should this code compile or not?

Comment: @quant_dev: It compiles for me with 1.49 and gcc. Anyways the question is, assuming that its a compiler and/or library problem, what are you going to do if you can not upgrade?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I've changed the key type to `std::string`. It works fine now.

Comment: This still fails with Boost 1.49 and VC 2008. However, VC 2010 compiles it without error.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Since VC 2010 is said to be more standard-compliant than VC 2008, what you say suggests that g++ was right to compile this code ;-)

Comment: @quant_dev: it turns out that VC 2008 is within rights to not compile the code - see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in VS2008 (as I mistakenly claimed in an earlier edit to this answer). The C++03 standard requires that the key type for an associative container, like `std::map`, must be 'assignable' (per Table 69 in 23.1.2 "Associative containers").  And a `const std::string` is not assignable. Note that the C++11 standard seems to relax this requirement, but the new standard doesn't apply to since VC++ 2008.

It's not clear to me that a compiler is required to diagnose code that tries to use `std::map` with a non-assignable key, so I don't think one can claim that GCC or VC++ 2010 are accepting this code improperly (I think it falls into the area of undefined code that works as you might expect, even though there's no guarantee it'll work).  However it is clear that it's OK for VC++ 2008 to refuse to compile it.

All that said, I think that VC++ 2008's library parameterizing the allocator's `address()` function on the map's key rather than map's element is still suspect (see the first edit of this answer for details if you're interested), but I don't think there's any real bug there since the `std::pair<>` used to hold the map element will always be set up such that key part will be at the same address as the whole element.